# Android setInexactRepeating killing battery

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarm, battery

Some of my app users are complaining that my app is killing their batterys but im having a hard time figuring out the issue. Can anyone spot where I might be going wrong?

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.walkingroutes.beta01

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent callingIntent) {
           long interval = 86400000;//set interval 86400000 = 24 hours
           AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE); 
           int alarmType = AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP;
           long timeOrLengthofWait = AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES;
           Intent intent = new Intent(context, UpdaterService.class); 
           PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, -1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); 
           alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);
      } 
}
```

Comment: what would make you think its your alarm causing the problem?

Comment: I cant really think of what else it could be. This alarm calls a intent which basically loops through a restful json updating the apps database.

Comment: well I can tell you its probably not the alarm